# How to hide a row only useful to admins so that users don't change the list view?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I solely want users to see data rather than have the ability to change list views or settings on my SharePoint site. Is it possible to do so without code and something built onto SharePoint?

I've tried the content query web part. In the red rectangle is what I wish for users to **not** see. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Just change the list permissions in the List Settings to only allow Read access to everyone but site owners.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by breaking the permission or changing the existing permissions for this list item and allow only Site Owners or whomever you want to allow to change the item. And for others you can have the read access permission.